# How do I take a user input, validate it as an integer, and use it to create a number of rectangles?

Tags: java

I'm pretty new to coding, and right now, I'm trying to create a script (if that's what you call it) and draw a number of rectangles that a user inputs in random locations. Right now, I have some difficulty sorting out my code:

```
import cs1.Keyboard;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;


public class Rectangles extends Applet{
    public static void main (String[] args){
        String message;

        System.out.println ("Enter an integer:");

        message = Keyboard.readString();

        String input = message;
        int inputInt;
        try{
            inputInt = Integer.parseInt(input);
        } 
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Not an integer; please use a valid integer");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        System.out.println ("You entered \"" + message + "\"");
    }


public void paint (Graphics page){
    for(int i=1; i < message; i++){
        int width = 10 + (int) (Math.random() * 40);
        int height = 10 + (int) (Math.random() * 40);
        int x = (int) (Math.random() * (getWidth() - width));
        int y = (int) (Math.random() * (getHeight() - height));
        page.drawRect (width,height,x,y);
        }
    }
}
```

Please pardon my code if it's messy! Anyway, I'm trying to get the user input (message) into public void paint, but I can't seem to transfer variables across public classes. When I try to combine the functions, I get a whole mess of errors:

```
Rectangles.java:25: error: illegal start of expression
    public void paint (Graphics page){
    ^
Rectangles.java:25: error: illegal start of expression
    public void paint (Graphics page){
           ^
Rectangles.java:25: error: ';' expected
    public void paint (Graphics page){
                     ^
Rectangles.java:25: error: ';' expected
    public void paint (Graphics page){
                                    ^
```

However, if I leave the code alone, I get:

```
Rectangles.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
for(int i=1; i < message; i++){
                 ^
symbol:   variable message
location: class Rectangles
```

I'm not sure how to organize this so that I can generate the amount of rectangles desired by the user: can anyone help me work the script out so that the variable can be used by public void paint?

Comment: You're mixing user paradigms, if you're using a graphical interface, you don't want to use a command line interface (and visa versa). Applet's don't (traditionally) have a `main` method, so that's kind of the wrong place to start, I'd also recommend that you avoid applets altogether, apart from been troublesome, they are no longer really supported (the applet plugin is been dropped by browser developers)

Comment: Message doesn't exist outside of `main`. It's out of scope.

Comment: The only error I get is with `for(int i=1; i < message; i++){` is because `messages` is out of scope. My general recommendation is to take a step back.  If you're new to Java/programming, go back to basics and understand how variable scope works, understand how information can be passed around a program. Once you've got that working, then you can start moving onto the more complex subject of graphics and user interfaces

Answer (score 0):

In your code message is a string and you are using inside it for loop and comparing it with integer variable.
First replace message with inputInt then your for loop should work.

According to Oracle docs -

public void paint(Graphics g)
Paints this canvas.
Most applications that subclass Canvas should override this method in order to perform some useful operation (typically, custom painting of the canvas). The default operation is simply to clear the canvas. Applications that override this method need not call super.paint(g).

Did you subclass Canvas? I think you have not subclassed canvas that is why this method is throwing error.

Hope this solve your query.